# Java Generic with bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between the class declarations

```
public abstract class Super1<T extends Super1<T>> {...}
```

and

```
public abstract class Super2<T extends Super2<? super T>> {...}
```

Using the 1st method, I was able to create a sub classes (similar to `Enum` types in Java)

```
public class Sub1 extends Super1<Sub1> {...}
```

but I wanted to know if a super class declaration like 2nd is possible at all.., is there any meaning to it, but I was not able to create a sub class like

```
public class Sub2 extends Super2<Object> {...}
```

I thought Object can be used as super type for `T`?? Also another form I can think of is

```
public abstract class Super3<T extends Super3<? extends T>>
```

I am trying to learn generics and any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use `Super2<Object>` because `Object` does not `extends Super2<Object>`.

Comment: Something like `class Super1<T extends Super1<T>>` is not useful; you should just use `class Super1<T>` instead.

Comment: @Sebastian, yes I was not able to create a class sub like, public class Sub extends Super2<Object>, but I was still able to create a sub class as, public class Sub extends Super2<Sub>. But since the type parameter is defined as Super2<? extends T>, I was guessing Super2<Object> is a valid substitute to it.

Comment: @newacct, class Super1<T extends Super1<T>> is a valid declaration, I am sure thats what is used in Enum types in java

Comment: @JKV: It is valid, but not useful. Show me one case where it works where `class Super1<T>` doesn't.

Comment: @newacct, I think this link can help http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206

Comment: @JKV: The bound is not used in that example at all. Works just fine without the bound.

Comment: @newacct, if there is not use for a self-referential generic type, as I get from the discussion, I am starting to wonder why its allowed in the language construct in the first place?

Comment: @JKV: There could be a rare situation where it is used, but that is not the case in your code or in the examples on that page. A case where it is used is if, for example, if you have a singly-linked list node, parameterized on the type of the "next" node, and you have a method inside the node class to iterate over the nodes starting from that one, then you would have a "current node" variable of `Node<T>` and the fact that the "next" node type (`T`) is a subtype of `Node<T>` is used. But this is a contrived example as it's weird to have a linked list where the node class can be subclassed.

Comment: @newacct,I am learning generics in java, understanding more about Types. Even I found out Self-referential types may fail if the class hierarchies have multilevel inheritance, which make them unusable for fluent interface designs. In your contrived example  I think if there is a another subtype Node<T> that extends from the Node in the second level, then it may not work. Like A<-B<-C, say if A is the base node type and B extends A and C extends B, which we can say C is a subtype of A too, But <T extends A<T>>, I can created B as B extends A<B>, but I cant create C in a similar way from B.

Answer (score 6):

Those kinds of declaration often comes into picture when you are dealing with *self-referential generic types* with *inheritance*. The keywords here are - ***Self-Referential***, and ***inheritance***.

Let us understand this with an example. Suppose we have a class `Car` which implements a `Comparable<Car>`, and a subclass of `Car` - `Mercedes`:

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car> { ... }
class Mercedes extends Car { }
```

Now, you would also want the `Mercedes` to be comparable, so you might think that let's implement a `Comparable<Mercedes>` there, and the you do:

```
class Mercedes extends Car implements Comparable<Mercedes> { }
```

.. and there is where you get an error. Issue is that, now `Mercedes` class implements both `Comparable<Car>` and `Comparable<Mercedes>`, which is not allowed.

**Futher Read on this:**

- [Can a class implement different instantiations of the same generic interface?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#Can%20a%20class%20implement%20different%20instantiations%20of%20the%20same%20parameterized%20interface?)

So, you remove that `Comparable<Mercedes>` from there. Now you're left with `Mercedes` class implementing `Comparable<Car>`.

then you create a class, which uses self-referential type parameter like this:

```
class Garage<T extends Comparable<T>> { }
```

And while creating an instance of that, with both `Car` and `Mercedes`, you do like this:

```
Garage<Car> carComp = new Garage<Car>();
Garage<Mercedes> mercedesComp = new Garage<Mercedes>();
```

Can you spot the error? Yes there it is in the 2nd declaration. `Mercedes` type argument can not be used, because it doesn't satisfy the bounds `T extends Comparable<T>`. As `Mercedes` implements a `Comparable<Car>`. So what to do now?

Here comes the use of that declaration. Let's change your class `Garage` to something like this:

```
class Garage<T extends Comparable<? super T>> { }
```

.. and then your 2 instantiation will pass successfully, as now `Mercedes` satisfies the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation., I have one more question.., can I have a declaration like public abstract class Super2<T extends Super2<? super T>> {...}.., note Super2 being used twice (T extends Super2<? super T>>).., if this is a valid declarations then what could be a possible sub class of it! I greatly appreciate your answer

Comment: @JKV Yes you can have such declaration. Actually that is the real self-referential generic type.

Comment: Try `class Sub extends Super<Sub>`

Comment: Yes that correct! class Sub extends Super2<Sub> is still valid if my Super2 is defined as class Super2<T extends Super2<T>> (which I think is how classes based on Enum types are defined), but I have a bounded wildcard <T extends Super2<? super T>>, instead of just <T extends Super2<T>. The bounded wildcard allows me to create only sub class which are the same as without the bounded wildcard. I tried different combination to my knowledge, and I cannot come up with a correct sub class for the bounded wildcard that is different. Thanks for the reply.